# Is it possible to block the profile tab configuration on a windows 2008R2 domain?

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, user-profiles, roaming-profiles

We have a windows 2008R2 domain where the users profiles are configured through the profile tab under the users properties in Active directory Users and computers.

[image: User properties - profile tab]

In this scenario when a user logs into a computer, the profile folder is stored on the location that the 'profile path' points to. Is there a way to block this configuration when the user is logged in to a server so it is stored on the server where the user is logged in to?

Comment: So basically you want roaming profiles?

Comment: nop, basically what I want is roaming profiles not occurring when login to servers.

Comment: clear the profile path and roaming profiles are disabled.

Comment: It´s not that simple. We need to maintain both configurations; roaming profiles when login to computers and local profiles when login to servers.

Comment: remote desktop to a terminal server uses the Terminal Services Profile path, which is in a different tab.

Comment: Forgot to mention, to see the terminal services profile path, you need to enable advanced features, which you can find in the menu on the main window below View I think.

Comment: There is another thing to keep in mind. We need to apply different settings depending on the OU the server is located, and if we configure the Terminal Services profile path through the user´s properties this cannot be accomplished.